# A function has a primitive must has no discontinuities of second kind?

Tags: analysis

> A function has a primitive must has no discontinuities of second kind?

Suppose $f(x)$ is a function with a primitive $F(x)$, then $f(x)=F'(x)$. If $x_0$ is a discontinuity of second kind of $f$, then either $f(x_0+)$ or $f(x_0-)$ does not exist. I have thought about Darboux theorem, but I don't know how to prove it or give a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f'(x_0+)$ and $f'(x_0-)$ both exist and they are not equal. Let us say $f'(x_0-)<f'(x_0+)$.  Choose $a,b$ such that $f'(x_0-)<a<b<f'(x_0+)$. Then there exists $r>0$ such that $f'(x) <a$ for all $x$ in $(x_0-r,x_0)$ and $f'(x) >b$ for all $x$ in $(x_0,x_0+r)$. Apply Darboux Theorem to the interval $(x_0-r,x_0+r)$ to get a contradiction. [No value between $a$ and $b$ is attained by $f'$ in this interval].

The case $f'(x_0-) >f'(x_0+)$ can be handled by just changing $f$ to $-f$.